# Sql server express

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-express

I have two computers in same local network.

One computer (comp1) have sql express database and have main application and other computer (comp2) have client application which need to access to data in sql server.

The problem is, how to ensure when comp1 is turned off that a comp2 has the latest data with him before the shutdown comp1 (offline mode). Comp2 work with offline data (select , insert data local) and when comp1 is turned on data from comp2
synchronized with sql server.

What is best practice to ensure this? I must use only sql server express because it is free.

Comment: why not use a proper `Windows Server` to hold the database ?

Comment: The client not want to use  third computer.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question as far as I could guess your problem. However, add code and description so that more people with knowledge of the subject will see it. Please edit in the specific error-message you're encountering in case that's necessary to identify the specific problem. Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

Welcome user6623705 :)

I think the keywqord you searching for is 'replication'. I don't have that much experience with replication with MSSQL-server but the MSDN might be a good source fot this.

If you can't install a server on your client try to work with a sql server compact-database.

On application startup you can sync the data by yourself (by your code) to a local database. These datas you can replicate every 5 minutes to your server if available. If not - not. If the server restartet you can begin sync again. I guess you got the point.

**Edit1:** [Here is the link to the MSDN entry about replication.](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165700(v=sql.90).aspx)

**Edit2:** Here are some stackoverflow links about the same topic.

- [Setup up c# to save to local database when offline and update/send to mysql when online](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9607488/setup-up-c-sharp-to-save-to-local-database-when-offline-and-update-send-to-mysql)
- [Store in local database when remote SQL Server unavailable and then sync when connected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32759429/store-in-local-database-when-remote-sql-server-unavailable-and-then-sync-when-co)
- [Best means to store data locally when offline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901238/best-means-to-store-data-locally-when-offline)